# Connect to .onion websites on tor using python?

Tags: python, tor

Here is the code that i have till now

```
import socks
import socket
import requests
import json

socks.setdefaultproxy(proxy_type=socks.PROXY_TYPE_SOCKS5, addr="127.0.0.1", port=9050)
socket.socket = socks.socksocket

data = json.loads(requests.get("http://freegeoip.net/json/").text)
```

and it works fine. The problem is when i use a `.onion` url it shows error

> Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known

After researching a little i found that although the http request is made over `tor` the resolution still occours over clearnet. What is the proper way so i can also have the domain resolved over tor network to connect to `.onion` urls ?

Comment: You can't just connect over HTTP - Have you looked at the excellent Python [Stem package for Tor?](https://stem.torproject.org/)

Comment: @samiles let me have a look at that now :)

Comment: You can find a monkeypatch for urllib2 [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5148589/python-urllib-over-tor?answertab=votes#tab-top)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try to avoid the monkey patching if possible.  If you're using modern version of requests, then you should have this functionality already.

```
import requests
import json

proxies = {
    'http': 'socks5h://127.0.0.1:9050',
    'https': 'socks5h://127.0.0.1:9050'
}

data = requests.get("http://altaddresswcxlld.onion",proxies=proxies).text

print(data)
```

It's important to specify the proxies using the `socks5h://` scheme so that DNS resolution is handled over SOCKS so Tor can resolve the `.onion` address properly.

Answer (score 0):

There is a more simple solution for this, but therefore you will need Kali Linux. If you have this OS, you can install tor service and kalitorify, start tor service with: **sudo service tor start** and start kalitorify with **sudo kalitorify -t**. Now your trafic will be send through tor and you can access .onion sites just as they would be normal sites.