# Unable to use Stem and Tor in Python to change my IP address?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tor, stem

I am currently trying to follow the a script I found online here: [Periodic Tor IP Rotation](https://codeburst.io/anonymous-web-crawling-in-10-minutes-edff782decdc)

The code I am trying to use is the following:

```
import requests
from stem import Signal
from stem.control import Controller
with Controller.from_port(port = 9051) as controller:
  controller.authenticate()
  controller.signal(Signal.NEWNYM)
proxies = {
  "http": "http://127.0.0.1:8118"
}
headers = {
  'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_1) AppleWebKit/537.73.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/7.0.1 Safari/537.73.11'
}
r = requests.get("http://icanhazip.com", proxies=proxies, headers=headers)
print(r.text)
```

However, my ip address doesn't change using this. Does anyone have any idea how I can modify it? Thanks.

Comment: Can you ditch Privoxy and use Tor's SOCKS proxy directly as shown here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43823166/892493

Comment: Is privoxy not usable in this case? I have little understanding what works.

Comment: If you aren't using privoxy for anything except HTTP proxy for Python -> Tor then there's no reason to put it between Tor and Python anymore.  A long time ago that's what many examples used because requests did not have SOCSK5h support so it was a necessary layer.  Now if you can use requests[socks] then Privoxy is unnecessary.  I'm not sure that's why you don't see the IP change between requests but I'd be interested to see if the signal works when you are using Tor's SOCKS proxy directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to be give a password to the authenticate() function.

Example:

```
    with Controller.from_port(port=9051) as controller:
        controller.authenticate(password='tor') # password came from your torrc file
        print("Success!")
        controller.signal(Signal.NEWNYM)
        print("New Tor connection processed")
```