# How can I send Tor requests to a website with stem?

Tags: python, python-3.x, networking, tor, stem

I would like **to send Tor requests to the website** I entered.

I cannot find an answer to my current question about StackOverflow, so I ask the question.

**If you have found an answer that answers my question, I would be very happy to receive an answer!**

Comment: stem is not really made to do requests over Tor to a website. There are plenty of other libraries that can do this. Your best bet is to use [requests](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/) with the [socks](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/advanced/#socks) option to specify Tor's socks5 proxy. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43682909/connect-to-onion-websites-on-tor-using-python/43823166#43823166) is an example, and plenty others like it are here on StackOverflow.